# PhpStorm with PHPUnit: PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter not found

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I am trying to use PHPUnit in PhpStorm (on a Mac). Therefore I tried adding the `pear` path and `phpunit` path to the include path of PhpStorm (the ones I found through `which pear` on the command line) - it tells me that phpunit was not found.

I also tried to use PHPUnit with the custom autoloader generated by composer (the `phpunit` package is installed), I then receive another error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter' not found
```

If I run phpunit on the console normally everything works:

```
phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/*Test.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reading docs first: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Comment: I'd suggest to use PHAR option -- works better than any other. In any case -- this may be similar/you may find some useful hints there -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31430

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I used the default php interpreter which phpStorm suggested to me. This was version `PHP 5.5` though and not the `5.6` version in my terminal.

After changing the interpreter to an up-to-date php version (`5.6` or `7.0`) it worked with the PHAR Option.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, you can also try to downgrade `phpunit/php-code-coverage` to `3.3` as described in this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/phpstorm-homestead-phpunit